# How to write JS that will count date and change table color?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I'm trying to create some JavaScript that calculates the difference between 2 input dates. If result is smaller then 24 hours, table row needs to be colorized as red.

I'll give some codes below;

```
class Campaigns(models.Model):

   start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Starting Date")
   end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Ending Date")
   broadcast = models.CharField(choices=BROADCAST_STATUS, blank=False, verbose_name="Broadcast Situtation", max_length=10)
```

This is my table rows :

```
{% for campaign in campaigns %}
   <tr>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.agency }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.brand }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.channel }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.target_group }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.start_date }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.end_date }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.date_to_take_place }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.day_part }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.impression }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.broadcast }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So what i need to calculate is,

```
result = campaign.start_date - campaign.end_date
if result < 24 hours:
    set table row color to red.
```

Thanks for any tip/solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you don't need JavaScript for it, because I don't see any **inputs** in your code. You just need simple property to return True/False if diff between start and end date is below 24 hours.

```
class Campaigns(models.Model):

    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Starting Date")
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Ending Date")
    broadcast = models.CharField(choices=BROADCAST_STATUS, blank=False, verbose_name="Broadcast Situtation", max_length=10)

    @property
    def below_24h(self):
        # check self.end_date - self.start_date here
        # and return True/False
```

Now in template:

```
{% for campaign in campaigns %}
{% if campaign.below_24h %}
   <tr style="color: red">
{% else %}
   <tr>
{% endif %}
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.agency }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.brand }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.channel }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.target_group }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.start_date }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.end_date }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.date_to_take_place }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.day_part }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.impression }}</td>
     <td class="text-center">{{ campaign.broadcast }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've tried result = self.start_date - self.end_date , but ofc it didn't respond like i wanted. How can i gather the day difference?

Comment: Try ```diff = (self.end_date - self.start_date).days``` - it should return number of days, so if it is below 1, that means it is less than 24h

Comment: That worked thanks, but table row doesn't become red even if result is lower or equal to 1

Comment: Did you add ```return True if diff <= 0 else False```?

Comment: if diff <= 1 : return True else return False , that's how i wrote it

Comment: That should work. Put print inside property to check if its true or false. If it works, and table row's text is not red, the problem is with CSS. Something might override the ```color```, for example ```text-center``` class. ```Color``` actualy changes text color. Try to change it to ```background: red```

Comment: I tried it returns true but i think it's because i use bootstrap table structure. Probably bootstrap overrides your style:color-red. Any idea how can i override this?

Comment: <tr {% if campaign.below_24h %} style="background-color: red" {% endif %}> i did your condition as in-line and it worked, thanks for the tip and the help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<input type="date">` you can use something like this:

```js
const inputHandler = ()=>{
  if(Math.floor( (Date.parse(dateOne.value) - Date.parse(dateTwo.value)) / 86400000)) {
    bg.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    bg.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
  }
}

dateOne.oninput = inputHandler;
dateTwo.oninput = inputHandler;
inputHandler();
```

```css
#bg {
width:5rem;
height:5rem;
padding: 1rem;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:0.8em;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<input id="dateOne" type="date" value="1970-01-01">
<input id="dateTwo" type="date" value="1970-01-03">
<div id="bg">Try changing the right input to 1970-01-01</div>
```